# rails Devise authenticated routes in integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, integration-testing

I want to test every route in an application, and learned I should do that in an integration test: [Where to test routes in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290245/where-to-test-routes-in-ruby-on-rails)

However I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:286:in `block in authenticated'
```

It's well-mentioned online that you can't use Devise::TestHelpers in integration testing --
[Devise Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-devise/QPOzZ1n6mfg), 
[Devise Github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers)

---

**How can I test routes like the following?**

```
# config/routes.rb

devise_for :users

authenticated :user do
  root to: 'static#home'
end

root to: 'static#landing'
```

I am running test unit tests with `$ rake test:integration`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Integration tests** are important for your application work flow. They can tell about your **URL definition** more clearly.

Check the [post](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29) by `nicholaides`, that explains the cause of this error and the solution in Authenticated routes.

Still the problem is:

Devise has its own methods and you can't use **Devise::TestHelpers** in ruby. So how can you test? Well you need to include the **Devise::TestHelpers** somehow.

Well, if you're using RSpec, you can put the following inside a file named `spec/support/devise.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

This is specified [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

**But wait..........** Again, you can run into this same issue with `Test::Unit`.

Then?

So, you just need to add the devise test helpers to **test/test_helper.rb**.

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Devise::TestHelpers work by putting things directly into your session. When running integration tests with Capybara, you don't have access to the server-side session. You just have access to the browser.

In our application, our integration tests use helper methods like this, that interact with Devise through the user interface:

```rb
def authenticate(user, password = nil)
  password ||= FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)[:password]
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in 'email', with: user.email
  fill_in 'password', with: password
  click_on 'Login'
  expect(current_path).to eq welcome_path
end
```